# Which one is the best ubuntu version currently for ROS? (Full installment)

Tags: rosinstall, ubuntu-precise, ubuntu, ubuntu-quantal

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I cannot decide between the various Ubuntu versions to install ROS. I have Ubuntu 13.10 but it is not supported. I didn't use other versions before so i want the one that will not crash often and will run smoothly with ROS & programming languages like jave etc.

I am **dual booting** so i want the version which provides all packages etc of ROS.

So any suggestions which one to install?
**UBUNTU 12.04 ? 12.10? 13.04?**

P.S. I am a **beginner** on both.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/154386/which-one-is-the-best-ubuntu-version-currently-for-ros?-(full-installment)/) by [Abdul](https://answers.ros.org/users/14906/abdul/) on ROS Answers with karma: 27 on 2014-04-17

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Right now (April 2013) your best bet is Ubuntu 12.04 with ROS Hydro.

Ubuntu Trusty 14.04 is the new LTS and was released today. In 1-2 months ROS Indigo will be released and the recommendation will be Ubuntu 14.04 and ROS Indigo. However, the migration from Hydro to Indigo should be relatively easy so I wouldn't wait on that, but instead get started and upgrade at your leisure.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2014-04-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Abdul](https://answers.ros.org/users/14906/abdul/) on 2014-04-17**:
So do you suggest me to install 12.04 for now and update it when ROS Indigo is ready? OR shall i run 12.04 on virtual box? I don't think it will be smooth and efficient though.

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2014-04-17**:
It's up to you, the best option right now is 12.04 and Hydro either in a VM or in a separate partition. Later you can choose to update to 14.04 and Indigo if you so choose. Hydro will be maintained for at least another year, and even then you should be ok, so there is no rush to update.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-04-17**:
12.04 is Ubuntu's Long Term Stable release, so it will be more stable and supported for a long time. They've recently released a 12.04.4 with a new kernel, so it runs well on recent hardware.

**Comment by [Codehead](https://answers.ros.org/users/29075/codehead/) on 2018-03-12**:
Is Ubuntu 14.04 still the best OS for running ROS?

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2018-03-12**:
This is always the best place to get an answer to this question (including a recommended version): https://wiki.ros.org/Distributions